# Proper way to clear asynchronous work in redux middleware

Tags: promise, redux, es6-promise

I have the following middleware that I use to call similar async calls:

```
import { callApi } from '../utils/Api';

import generateUUID from '../utils/UUID';

import { assign } from 'lodash';

export const CALL_API = Symbol('Call API');

export default store => next => action => {
  const callAsync = action[CALL_API];

  if(typeof callAsync === 'undefined') {
    return next(action);
  }

  const { endpoint, types, data, authentication, method, authenticated } = callAsync;

  if (!types.REQUEST || !types.SUCCESS || !types.FAILURE) {
    throw new Error('types must be an object with REQUEST, SUCCESS and FAILURE');
  }

  function actionWith(data) {
    const finalAction = assign({}, action, data);
    delete finalAction[CALL_API];

    return finalAction;
  }

  next(actionWith({ type: types.REQUEST }));

  return callApi(endpoint, method, data, authenticated).then(response => {
    return next(actionWith({
      type: types.SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        response
      }
    }))
  }).catch(error => {
    return next(actionWith({
      type: types.FAILURE,
      error: true,
      payload: {
        error: error,
        id: generateUUID()
      }
    }))
  });
};
```

I am then making the following calls in `componentWillMount` of a component:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchResults();
    this.props.fetchTeams();
  }
```

`fetchTeams` for example will dispatch an action that is handled by the middleware, that looks like this:

```
export function fetchTeams() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch({
      type: 'CALL_API',
      [CALL_API]: {
        types: TEAMS,
        endpoint: '/admin/teams',
        method: 'GET',
        authenticated: true
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Both the success actions are dispatched and the new state is returned from the reducer.  Both reducers look the same and below is the `Teams` reducer:

```
export const initialState = Map({
  isFetching: false,
  teams: List()
});

export default createReducer(initialState, {
  [ActionTypes.TEAMS.REQUEST]: (state, action) => {
    return state.merge({isFetching: true});
  },

  [ActionTypes.TEAMS.SUCCESS]: (state, action) => {
    return state.merge({
      isFetching: false,
      teams: action.payload.response
    });
  },

  [ActionTypes.TEAMS.FAILURE]: (state, action) => {
    return state.merge({isFetching: false});
  }
});
```

The component then renders another component that dispatches another action:

```
render() {
  <div>
   <Autocomplete items={teams}/>
  </div>
}
```

Autocomplete then dispatches an action in its `componentWillMount`:

```
class Autocomplete extends Component{
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.init({ props: this.exportProps() }));
  }
```

if an error happens in the autocomplete reducer that is invoked after the SUCCESS reducers have been invoked for `fetchTeams` and `fetchResults` from the original calls in `componentWillMount` of the parent component and the error will be handled in the `Promise.catch` of the `callApi` method that happens in the middleware.

`return callApi(endpoint, method, data, authenticated).then(response => {
        return next(actionWith({
          type: types.SUCCESS,
          payload: {
            response
          }
        }))
      }).catch(error => {
        return next(actionWith({
          type: types.FAILURE,
          error: true,
          payload: {
            error: error,
            id: generateUUID()
          }
        }))
      });
    };`

This is because it is happening with in the same tick of the event loop.  If I introduce some asynchronicity in the `Autcomplete` `componentWIllMount` function then the error is not handled  in the Promise catch handler of the middleware

`class Autocomplete extends Component{
      componentWillMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.props.dispatch(actions.init({ props: this.exportProps() }));
        });
      }`

Should I have the `callApi` function execute on a separate event loop tick?

Comment: I'm kind of confused what the actual question is.  Are you asking how to keep errors from happening in reducers, or how to recover from such an error?

Comment: No, what is happening is that if if the Asynchronous action completes and the SUCCESS action completes but an error happens after that then that error is propagated to the catch handler of the middleware.

This is because it all happens in the same tick of the event loop.

Comment: If an error happens after the SUCCESS action completes, I would like it to have its own stack trace and not be propagated to the catch handler

Comment: Well, as I said in the Redux issue, this is all really a question about how Promises behave, not specifically about Redux middleware or reducers.  (Actually had someone point out the other day that an "AJAX thunk" example I'd written would show the same behavior you're describing.)  I'm still not clear on what exactly you _want_ to happen.  If an error is thrown inside of a promise callback and not caught, execution jumps to the next `catch()` promise in the sequence.  That's how they work.

Comment: The error is actually happening in the componentWillMount of a different component that invoked the action and the middleware.  When the error occurrs I get the stack trace leading back to the catch handler of the middleware and not the stack trace in the component.  This is because as  you pointed out, this is all happening from the same event loop tick as the resolve handler of the promise.  

I would like the stack trace and error that happens in the child component to point me in the right direction and not the middleware catch handler

Comment: I'm really not sure there's anything you can do about that.  Calling `dispatch` will synchronously notify subscribers, and React may render as a result.  If you put a breakpoint in `componentDidMount` of any component in a Redux app, you'll generally see a long stack trace that goes back to the original `dispatch`.  About the only vague suggestion I can think of would be to move the actual `dispatch` call to be in another `then` after the original `catch`.